# Use Async wait to let .then disappear

Tags: javascript, async-await

Request:

async await for this line: fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json())

So there shouldn't be any .then() calls anymore!

The original code:

```js
    const urls = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'
]

const getData = async function() {
  const [ users, posts, albums ] = await Promise.all(urls.map(url =>
      fetch(url).then(resp => resp.json())
  ));
  console.log('users', users);
  console.log('posta', posts);
  console.log('albums', albums);
}
getData();
```

What i try in my JS:

```
 const [ users, posts, albums ] = await Promise.all(urls.map
 (url=>
     resp = await fetch(url);
     data = await resp.json();
 ));
```

I want the output is as same as the original code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns nothing, and is not marked `async` (which is required from any function using `await`). Furthermore, it's not cool to not declare variables.

```
const [users, posts, albums] = await Promise.all(urls.map(async url => {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const data = await resp.json();
    return data;
}));
```

EDIT: also, what guest271314 said - need curlies now that the inner function is not a simple expression.

Comment: `resp.json` looks synchronous so `await` won't work because it does not return a promise

Comment: @slebetman: ["looks"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)? Also, `await` works on non-promises just fine: `await 42` evaluates to `42`.